# JavaScript defer images too slow

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following JavaScript code that I put into the header of my page to defer load images on my page.

```
function init() {
var imgDefer = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var i=0; i<imgDefer.length; i++) {
if(imgDefer[i].getAttribute('data-defer')) {
imgDefer[i].setAttribute('src',imgDefer[i].getAttribute('data-defer'));
} } }
window.onload = init;
```

and here is my html

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAD/ACwAAAAAAQABAAACADs=" data-defer="image.jpg"/>
```

But unfortunately it takes too long to execute, in other words it takes long time to change the **src** value in **img** tag.
What I am doing wrong here, let me know if there exists some efficient way to defer images.

Regards.

Comment: No way for us to know what delay is. Number of images, sizes of images , other scripts in page, page load time etc. What is shown is about as efficient as you can get script-wise

Comment: `for(img of document.querySelectorAll('img[data-defer]')) img.src = img.dataset.defer;` wrote it a bit leaner, and removed the necessity to manually check wether the img has a `data-defer` attribute. But the performance impact should be small, unless you have a ton of images on your page. And even if you have, you'll have other *(performance)* problems than the execution time of a few lines of JS.

Comment: Yes, there are other .js files included in page as well. Please tell me where to put JavaScript code in question to run before other code.